# ListView in flutter with sticky side headers

Tags: flutter, dart

How to implement a ListView with alphabet shown as sticky side headers, similarly to the Telegram application?

[image]

For example, while we look at the countries that begin with the letter "E", the letter "E" is not scrolling as long as there are countries that begin with the letter "F". Then the letter "E" is changed to the letter "F".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution with Sticky Side Header

You have a package for that! The [flutter_sticky_header package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header).

[image]

Interesting points about the solution:

1. I used the [diacritic package](https://pub.dev/packages/diacritic) to remove the diacritics when indexing the list of `Persons`. You wouldn't want to exclude [all of Norway's Øyvind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98yvind), would you?
2. I used a `SplayTreeMap` to keep the Map sorted.
3. I used [Flutter Hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) for the `Persons` mapping, happening only when `contacts` is changed.

### Full source code

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:diacritic/diacritic.dart';
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sticky_header/flutter_sticky_header.dart';

part '66542479.alphabet.freezed.dart'; // File generated by freezed

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: DirectoryPage(contacts: dummyData),
    ),
  );
}

class DirectoryPage extends HookWidget {
  final List<Person> contacts;

  const DirectoryPage({Key key, this.contacts}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _mappedContacts = useState<SplayTreeMap<String, List<Person>>>(null);
    useEffect(() {
      _mappedContacts.value = contacts.fold<SplayTreeMap<String, List<Person>>>(
        SplayTreeMap<String, List<Person>>(),
        (acc, curr) {
          final firstChar = removeDiacritics(curr.name)[0];
          acc..[firstChar] ??= [];
          return acc..[firstChar].add(curr);
        },
      );
      return;
    }, [contacts]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: _mappedContacts.value.keys
            .map(
              (firstChar) => _StickyHeaderList(
                  firstChar: firstChar,
                  persons: _mappedContacts.value[firstChar]),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _StickyHeaderList extends StatelessWidget {
  final String firstChar;
  final List<Person> persons;

  const _StickyHeaderList({
    Key key,
    this.firstChar,
    this.persons,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverStickyHeader(
      overlapsContent: true,
      header: _SideHeader(text: firstChar),
      sliver: SliverPadding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
        sliver: SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
            ...persons.map((person) => PersonTile(person: person)).toList(),
            Divider(),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SideHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const _SideHeader({
    Key key,
    this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 6.0),
      child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0)),
    );
  }
}

class PersonTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Person person;

  const PersonTile({Key key, this.person}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(title: Text(person.name));
  }
}

final faker = Faker();
final dummyData = [
  ...List.generate(100, (index) => Person(name: faker.person.name())),
  Person(name: 'Øyvind')
];

@freezed
abstract class Person with _$Person {
  const factory Person({String name}) = _Person;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Nested `ListViews`.

[image]

Interesting points about the solution:

1. I used the [diacritic package](https://pub.dev/packages/diacritic) to remove the diacritics when indexing the list of `Persons`. You wouldn't want to exclude [all of Norway's Øyvind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98yvind), would you?
2. I used a `SplayTreeMap` to keep the Map sorted.
3. I used [Flutter Hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) for the `ScrollController` and the `Persons` mapping, happening only when `contacts` is changed.

### Full source code

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:diacritic/diacritic.dart';
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'my_file.freezed.dart'; // File generated by freezed

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: DirectoryPage(contacts: dummyData),
    ),
  );
}

class DirectoryPage extends HookWidget {
  final List<Person> contacts;

  const DirectoryPage({Key key, this.contacts}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _scrollController = useScrollController();
    final _mappedContacts = useState<SplayTreeMap<String, List<Person>>>(null);
    useEffect(() {
      _mappedContacts.value = contacts.fold<SplayTreeMap<String, List<Person>>>(
        SplayTreeMap<String, List<Person>>(),
        (acc, curr) {
          final firstChar = removeDiacritics(curr.name)[0];
          acc..[firstChar] ??= [];
          return acc..[firstChar].add(curr);
        },
      );
      return;
    }, [contacts]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scrollbar(
        controller: _scrollController,
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        child: ListView.separated(
          controller: _scrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final key = _mappedContacts.value.keys.elementAt(index);
            return Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(key, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36)),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: _mappedContacts.value[key]
                        .map((person) => PersonTile(person: person))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(),
          itemCount: _mappedContacts.value.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PersonTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Person person;

  const PersonTile({Key key, this.person}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(title: Text(person.name));
  }
}

final faker = Faker();
final dummyData = [
  ...List.generate(100, (index) => Person(name: faker.person.name())),
  Person(name: 'Øyvind')
];

@freezed
abstract class Person with _$Person {
  const factory Person({String name}) = _Person;
}
```

Comment: thank you soo much!! its working perfectly.